# API getting called multiple times

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, api

When testing the API I have noticed that it is getting called around 6 times, there is no for/foreach loop that would make it run several times in the code so am unsure as to why this may be happening.
The API runs every time a user goes onto the Landing Screen.
Any advice would be appreciated

```js
exports.getFilteredOpportunities = async (req, res) => {
    let mongoQuery = generateMongoQuery(req);
    try {
        const opps = await Opportunity.find(mongoQuery)
            .select(removeItems)
            .sort({
                createdAt: -1
            });
        res.status(200).json({
            opportunities: opps,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            status: "error",
            message: error,
        });
    }
};
```

GenerateMongoQuery function

```js
const generateMongoQuery = (req) => {
    let query = {};
    // search param used searching through Title field, ie. search=food
    if (req.query.search && req.query.search.length > 0) {
        query.$or = [{}, {}];
        query.$or[0].Title = query.$or[1].Description = new RegExp(
            `${req.query.search}`,
            "i"
        );
    }
    // location param, i.e location=Glasgow,Manchester
    if (req.query.location && req.query.location.length > 0) {
        query.location = {
            $in: req.query.location.split(",")
        };
    }
    // timeslot param, i.e timeslot=Evening,Morning
    if (req.query.timeslot && req.query.timeslot.length > 0) {
        query.timeslot = {
            $in: req.query.timeslot.split(",")
        };
    }
    // category param, returning corresponding id i.e category=
    if (req.query.category && req.query.category.length > 0) {
        query.category = {
            $in: req.query.category.split(",")
        };
    }
    // Dont load expired opportunities
    query.eventDate = {
        $gte: new Date().toDateString()
    };
    // Only return non-cancelled opportunities
    query.isCancelled = false;
    return query;
};
```

The landing Screen

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Opportunities from "../components/molecules/Opportunities";
import Filters from "../components/organisms/Filters";
import { IOpportunity } from "../Models/IOpportunity";
import OpportunitiesClient from "../Api/opportunitiesClient";
import Utils from "../Utils/Utils";
import FiltersClient from "../Api/filtersClient";
import { IFilters } from "../Models/IFilters";
import { ISelectedFilters } from "../Models/ISelectedFilters";

import Header from "../components/atoms/Header";
import Footer from "../components/atoms/Footer";

export default function LandingScreen(props) {
    const [opportunities, setOpportunities] = useState<IOpportunity[]>([]);
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState<IFilters[]>([]);
    const [checkedFilters, setCheckedFilters] = useState<
        ISelectedFilters | undefined
    >({
        Location: [],
        Category: [],
        Timeslot: [],
    });
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [allResultsLoaded, setAllResultsLoaded] = useState<boolean>(false);
    let pageToGet = 1;
    const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
    const [totalOpps, setTotalOpps] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        getOpportunities();
        getFilters();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTotalOpps(opportunities.length);
    }, [opportunities]);

    const handleScroll = () => {
        setScrollPosition(window.pageYOffset);
        let scrollHeight = 0;

        if ((props.scrollHeight === null) !== undefined) {
            scrollHeight = +props.scrollHeight;
        } else {
            scrollHeight = document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight;
        }

        if (
            window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop >=
            scrollHeight
        ) {
            if (allResultsLoaded === false) {
                setLoading(true);
            }
            setTimeout(() => {
                pageToGet += 1;
                getOpportunities();
            }, 600);
        }
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, { passive: true });

    const setItemChecked = (filtername: string, filterType: string) => {
        // reset page and results
        pageToGet = 1;
        setAllResultsLoaded(false);

        setCheckedFilters(
            Utils.setItemChecked(filtername, filterType, checkedFilters)
        );
    };

    const resetFilters = () => {
        // reset page and results
        pageToGet = 1;
        setAllResultsLoaded(false);

        checkedFilters.Location = [];
        checkedFilters.Category = [];
        checkedFilters.Timeslot = [];

        getOpportunities();
    };

    const getFilters = () => {
        FiltersClient.getAll().then((filters) => {
            setFilters(filters);
        });
    };

    const getOpportunities = () => {
        console.log(opportunities);
        OpportunitiesClient.getWithParams(
            Utils.getAxiosParams(checkedFilters)
        ).then((res) => {
            definePage(res);
            if (opportunities.length === res["opportunities"].length)
                setAllResultsLoaded(true);

            setLoading(false);
        });
    };

    const definePage = (res) => {
        if (pageToGet === 1) {
            setOpportunities(res["opportunities"].slice(0, 15));
        } else {
            setOpportunities(
                opportunities.concat(
                    res["opportunities"].slice(
                        opportunities.length,
                        opportunities.length + 15
                    )
                )
            );
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Header page="landing" includePostButton={true} />
            <div
                data-testid="test-div1"
                className="grid md:grid-cols-[150px_auto] sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-flow-col gap-4 mx-4 mb-5 my-10"
            >
                <div></div>
                <div className="card-container-title">
                    {totalOpps} Results{" "}
                    {checkedFilters.Location.length > 0 ? "(Filtered)" : ""}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div
                data-testid="test-div3"
                className="grid md:grid-cols-[150px_auto] sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-flow-col gap-4 mx-4"
            >
                <div>
                    <Filters
                        filters={filters}
                        getChecked={setItemChecked}
                        urlCall={getOpportunities}
                        resetFilters={resetFilters}
                        checkedFilters={checkedFilters}
                    />
                </div>

                <div
                    data-testid="test-div4"
                    className={isLoading ? "opacity-50" : ""}
                >
                    <div className="col-span-2">
                        <Opportunities
                            items={opportunities}
                            isLoading={isLoading}
                            allResultsLoaded={allResultsLoaded}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Why do you even have a state that tracks `opportunities.length`? Just use `opportunities.length` directly???

Comment: @vera. Good point. That's been rectified now. Thanks